# read.table: percent sign (%) and forward slah (/) in headers replaced by dot (.)

Tags: r, string, read.table

I have a csv file with headers, some of which contain the percent sign or forward slash, e.g.:

"Exp1_BSL_%LF", "Exp1_BSL_LF/HF".

When importing those files with read.table(header = TRUE) those signs are replaced by dots:

"Exp1_BSL_.LF", "Exp1_BSL_LF.HF".

I don't have experience working with strings in R so I don't have any clue what's causing this behaviour.

```
> read.table(text = "Subject,Exp1_BSL_SDNN,Exp1_BSL_LF/HF,Exp1_BSL_%LF
+ s1,123,123,123
+ s2,123,123,123", sep=",", header=TRUE)

Subject Exp1_BSL_SDNN Exp1_BSL_LF.HF Exp1_BSL_.LF
1      s1           123            123          123
2      s2           123            123          123
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R by default tries to makes sure that the dataframe you are importing have syntactically valid names using `check.names` which is `TRUE` by default. It does not allow column names with symbols like `%`, `/` (or other as defined in `make.names`).

We can, however, override this behavior using `check.names = FALSE`

```
read.table(text = "Subject,Exp1_BSL_SDNN,Exp1_BSL_LF/HF,Exp1_BSL_%LF
   s1,123,123,123
   s2,123,123,123", sep=",", header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

#  Subject Exp1_BSL_SDNN Exp1_BSL_LF/HF Exp1_BSL_%LF
#1      s1           123            123          123
#2      s2           123            123          123
```